# Using local kmz files on google maps

Tags: google-maps

I found a google maps api that allows me to overlay my map with a kmz/kml file however it must be hosted remotely. I have my kmz/kml files locally and would like to overlay them on my google maps, how can i get my local files to overlay my google map?

Comment: locally hosting a .kml file is not possible without an alternative method - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514785/loading-a-local-kml-file-using-google-maps

Comment: I will look into that library.

Comment: For some reason the layers will not load. @Mapperz

Comment: It is definetly possible to do something where the user can drag and drop a file on the map, and to render that data on the map. See an example here with OpenLayers: http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/drag-and-drop.html